# A question about engeinvalues for a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

**PROBLEM**

Consider the problem
\begin{eqnarray}
u_t && = c^2 u_{xx}, 0< x< \pi, t>0,\\
u(0,t) && = 0= u_x(\pi,t) + \gamma u(\pi,t), 0 \le t,\\
u(x,0) &&= f(x), 0 \le x \le \pi,
\end{eqnarray}
where $\gamma \in R$ and $f$ is a given real function.
$$

My problem is: deduct grafically that the equation bellow is satisfy for a infinity and countable of positive values of $\lambda$ for the equation
$$
 \sqrt{\lambda}\cos (\sqrt{\lambda} \pi) + \gamma \sin(\sqrt{\lambda} \pi) =0
$$
and, if $\lambda_1< \lambda_2 < ... < \lambda_n<...$ are eingenvalues for the ODE, obtained through the method of separation of variables $u(x,t) = \varphi(x) \psi(t)$, i.e
\begin{eqnarray} 
-\varphi ''  && = \lambda \varphi,\\
\varphi(0) && = 0 = \varphi '(\pi) + \gamma \varphi(\pi).
\end{eqnarray}
than $\lambda_n \to +\infty$, when $n \to + \infty$. Write the solution $u_n(x,t)$ which corresponds to the eigenvalue $\lambda_n$

**MY ATTEMPT**

I did a graphical analysis considering that the equation is are level curves of the function
$$
\xi (\lambda, \gamma) = \sqrt{\lambda}\cos (\sqrt{\lambda} \pi) + \gamma \sin(\sqrt{\lambda} \pi)
$$
The "roots" of the $\xi (\lambda, \gamma) = 0$ are the points where the curves cross the $\lambda$'s axis.

[image]

Note that, by the graph, it is possible to identify that the values of the lambdas are strictly increasing and that they increase more and more.

But I don't know if my analysis is correct, or if I'm being misled by my geometric intuition. Also, I don't know how this will help me find the $\lambda_n$ eigenvalue to complete the last part of the exercise.
I tried in every way to solve this equation "analytically". But I don't get any results. Any idea??

Thanks!!

Comment: You can rewrite your expression as $\tan \mu \pi=-\mu$, where $\mu=\sqrt{\lambda}$. Now your conclusion should be almost immediate since you know the graphs of $\tan$ and $-\mu$.